# Can't disable fonts in Font Book after fresh Mojave install

Tags: permission, font, mojave, font-book

I just finished installing macOS Mojave on a brand new 2018 MacBook Pro.

One of the first things I usually do is disable all unnecessary fonts.

This time, **the option to disable the font is grayed out for every single font**.

In the Finder the file permissions are as follows:

```
system: Read & Write
wheel: Read only
everyone: Read only
```

**How can I disable fonts in Font Book on OS X Mojave?**

Comment: it was like that on HighSierra as well

Comment: I have been using High Sierra for a year and it's been fine. Did the problem go away eventually or did you never solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Font Book in Mojave won't let us disable any fonts located in `/Library/Fonts`, where fonts are supposed to be installed for system-wide use. But I can disable/enable fonts with Font Book if they're located in `~/Library/Fonts` (inside your user's home folder).

If you take the other suggestion to make a new folder called `/Library/Fonts (disabled)` or `/Library/Fonts Disabled` or `/Library/Fonts I Hate` etc, moving any fonts into there will just make them disappear entirely out of Font Book. It's not exactly disabling them, it's just putting them into a place where Font Book isn't looking for fonts at all.

Better to move any unwanted system fonts into `~/Library/Fonts`, at least they will still be visible to Font Book, and you can easily enable them again if needed.

Comment: The usual reason for wanting to disable fonts is to remove them from the font menus of your apps.  The procedure you suggest will not do that.

Comment: I think this is a great idea, and I would have suggested it if I had thought of it. Tom, this technique will remove them from the menu once you deactivate them (the whole reason for this post).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that (as far as I know), Font Book in Mojave just does not allow disabling of the default fonts.

There are **two main locations** where fonts are stored under Mojave:

```
/Library/Fonts/
```

/Library/Fonts/ contains all the **general use fonts**, available to all users. These are the fonts I wanted to disable.

```
/System/Library/Fonts/
```

/System/Library/Fonts/ contains **fonts that are necessary for the system**.

I simply **moved all the fonts** from **/Library/Fonts/** to **/Library/Fonts (disabled)/**

It went fine and the system has not complained so far.

I did leave copies of the standard web fonts: Verdana, Times New Roman etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. Your method of manually moving the font worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the fonts you want to remove

and drag the over under Collection in a new folder.

Now you can delete or disable all fonts in that folder !

Comment: Disable is still grayed-out.